# Php upgrade on Hostgator not applying

Tags: php, webserver, symfony

I just bought hosting on Hostgator, built a local symfony project that I uploaded on the server, but I can't finish the deployment because symfony needs php 5.6, while I have 5.4.

So, I went on cPanel and update my php version to 5.6 through the php configuration menu. It said it updated, yet my `composer update --verbose` still tells me I'm on php 5.4 .  Alas, if I run `php -v` or `php --ini` through ssh, it still shows as php 5.4.

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Sounds like a question for [Server Fault](http://serverfault.com/)

Answer (score 2):

One solution can be your .htaccess file being read-only. Make sure the .htaccess file is writeable. Got the solution from here:
https://www.itechtics.com/unable-to-change-php-version-on-cpanel/

Answer (score 0):

Try editing your web/.htaccess file in your Symfony3 folder to add the following content:

AddHandler application/x-httpd-php56 .php

Then verify the phpinfo() shows the version as 5.6

**EDIT #2**
Hi there Ryncops, based on your comments, here are the 2 links I found that I got that information:

http://www.inmotionhosting.com/support/website/php/how-to-change-the-php-version-your-account-uses

http://www.inmotionhosting.com/support/website/php-configuration/using-multiple-php-versions-one-account

Maybe if you read those over some more, it will help. I think you should be able to get it working. Maybe try some experiments and see what happens.

Comment: Hello! Tried that, didn't work... any other hints? I am at the moment waiting for hostgator live chat... but they answer hard...

Comment: Thank you! I solved it, the issue was with the php cli. Apparently hostgator, and probably  other hosting companies, have more versions installed. I just didn't know how to access it,, but this link [helped me](http://www.drewkeller.com/blog/selecting-php-command-line-version-hostgator-shared-host)

Comment: Glad you got it working! You might want to post the specific answer, so that other people can find the answer as well on Stackoverflow.

Comment: .htaccess has nothing to php-cli

Answer (score 0):

I have solved it with the help of this link: [drewkeller.com](http://www.drewkeller.com/blog/selecting-php-command-line-version-hostgator-shared-host)

My issue was, in fact, with php cli, which was 5.4, and I needed 5.6. Apparently, hostgator, probably other hosting services, have multiple php cli versions installed, I just didn't know where to find the other versions.

Comment: Hi Ryncops. If you have access to the command line, try `whereis php56` to see where it might be.